# How to get multiple table values to gridview?

Tags: yii

I have two tables and i need to filter and put those two table data to gridview.i use joined two table like this

```
         $student=new Student;
         $marks=new AssimentMarks;

        $criteria_st=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->select    = 't.st_id,t.st_name,stu.ass_id,stu.marks_cr1,stu.marks_cr2,stu.marks_cr3,stu.marks_cr4,stu.marks_cr5';
        $criteria->join      = 'INNER JOIN assiment_marks stu ON stu.st_id=t.st_id';
        $criteria->condition = 'stu.ass_id=:ass_id';
        $criteria->params    = array(':ass_id'=>Yii::app()->session['modelcrite']['ass_id']);
        $criteria->addInCondition('t.st_id', $studentid);
```

return new  CActiveDataProvider($student, array('criteria'=>$criteria,));

but in gridviwe only show the student database values.it is show as .how can i pass two models to CActiveDataProvider ?

this is how data shows
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kogjz.jpg

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are they related somehow or what?

Comment: yes they are related.They are three tables assignments,assignments  marks and student table.I'm doing those things in assignments model assignment marks table refer assignments table id and student id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1) Foreign key in schema

Your assiment table should reference your student table with a foreign key, like this (assuming SQLite):

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE assiment_record(  
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    student_id INTEGER,
    cr1 INTEGER,
    cr2 INTEGER,
    cr3 INTEGER,
    cr4 INTEGER,
    cr5 INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY( student_id ) REFERENCES student(id)   -- FK goes in the CHILD table. 
);
```

### 2) Generate models with Gii:

**student -> models/Student.php**

**assiment_record -> models/AssimentRecord.php**

Gii is smart and guesses your relations:

```
// AssimentRecord.php looks good! No changes made!
public function relations()
return array(
    'student' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student', 'student_id'),
);
```

*The assiment record BELONGS TO the student*.

### 3) Tweak gii's output (Student.php)

But Gii's is not perfect, and does not know what your intentions are. The current student relation (HAS_MANY) returns an array, but **I don't want to deal with the array** (because I'm lazy!), so I change it into a HAS_ONE-relation instead:

```
// Student.php
public function relations()
{
    return array(
    // Change this:   'assimentRecords' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'AssimentRecord', 'student_id'),
    /* into this: */  'assimentRecord'  => array(self::HAS_ONE,  'AssimentRecord', 'student_id'),
    );
}
```

*The student HAS ONE assiment record*.

### 4) Display the grid:

```
// views/site/index.php  (Or wherever.)
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider( 'Student' );
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'assimentRecord.cr1',
        'assimentRecord.cr2',
        'assimentRecord.cr3',
        'assimentRecord.cr4',
        'assimentRecord.cr5',
    )
));
```

Comment: I'm confused with reference of student and assiment_record.it say that assiment_record id refer the student id.may be i'm incorrect,is it i need to change assiment_record.php relation function ?.please help me to understand this.Thank you

Comment: The FK on both sides refers to 'assiment_record.student_id'. Yii knows where to look because of the relation type. [Read more here.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship)

Comment: thank you for the help and i try your example as it is.i got same problem.But i debug it and i saw all the data in side the $dataProvider object,but the problem is how i can access it ?